# elasticsearch js update an index

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Hi guys I have an index which I want to update a part of using elastic search js

for example: I have this index:

```
{
        "_index" : "users",
        "_type" : "j_users",
        "_id" : "CpmE0G0BteODhj-lZNPP",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "email" : "alex@walla.co.il",
          "firstName" : "aa",
          "lastName" : "aa",
          "confirmed" : false,

        }
```

and I wish to change only the "confirmed" field to true, how do I do that?

```
await client.update({
      index: "users",
      id: "CpmE0G0BteODhj-lZNPP",
      body: {
        confirmed: true
      }
    });
```

I tried this according to the documentation but I get an error, can anyone tell me whats wrong with my syntax?

Comment: what error do you getting?

Comment: try to specify type, probably not using same version as in docs says..

Comment: I added a type and I still get an error , about a field that does not exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
await client.update({
      index: "users",
      type : "j_users" 
      id: "CpmE0G0BteODhj-lZNPP",
      body: {
        doc: {
        confirmed: true
      }
     }
    });
```

you can also try to add

```
 doc_as_upsert: true
```

Comment: I just needed to add type and it worked, thank you! please add this to your answer so I can accept it

Comment: yes, it depends which version of ES you use, glad it helped